# Laravel 7 404 Error with Route with more than 2 Levels

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-7

I'm facing a wired issue with Laravel where routes with multiple parameters (both mandatory/optional) aren't working.

**Environment Information**

- Local: Windows, XAMPP, PHP 7.3
- Production: Ubuntu 18.04, PHP 7.4

Initially, I suspected issue with .htaccess file but that seems not to be an issue.
This works perfectly on my Local, but for some reason, that doesn't work on Ubuntu Server.

The following code works perfectly.

```
Route::any('route/me/','Tst@routeme');
```

However, any of the following doesn't work:

```
Route::any('route/me/here/','Tst@routeme');

Route::any('route/me/here/{id?}','Tst@routeme');

Route::any('route/me/here/and/here','Tst@routeme');
```

Any suggestions where I can look up to fix this out, please?

Comment: I'm curious, why are yor local and production environments running different versions of PHP? Also, when you say the routes don't work, what exactly is happening?

Comment: you use Route::any instead of Route::get, so anything 'route/me' base on [Available Router Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing) will be check for get 'route/me', post 'route/me', put 'route/me', patch 'route/me', delete 'route/me', options 'route/me'. try to change ::any to ::get , and check on your terminal php artisan route:list

Comment: @spholt, I know that's ugly, but my local has other client projects which require the version. Hence the difference :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## updating my own question so that might be of some help for others.

I would say probably this is the last thing that someone (or at least me) failed to check. I tried to list the routes in my server and found my newly added route was not found.

```
php artisan route:list
```

Earlier, I cleared cache, restarted apache but didn't help. Finally found the following commands to be a lifesaver when routes are cache & aren't working.
So the thing that worked for me - clearing the "route" cache.

```
php artisan route:cache 
php artisan route:clear
```

My hearty thanks to @Spholt,@Akbar khan, @Spholt, @Gzai Kun for helping out.

Answer (score 2):

My first suggestion would be to place the route with most params at the top like:

```
Route::any('route/me/here/and/here','Tst@routeme');

Route::any('route/me/here/{id?}','Tst@routeme');

Route::any('route/me/here/','Tst@routeme');
```

It's more like which ever route matches first gets executed first so from top to bottom the least param route matches last.

Second thing i would suggest you to group the routes like:

```
Route::prefix('route/me')->group(function () {
    Route::get('here/and/here', 'Tst@routeme');
    Route::get('here/{id?}', 'Tst@routeme');
    Route::get('here', 'Tst@routeme');
});
```

for better readability...

Comment: Tried that as well, but didn't help much ;(

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you specifics on why this particular scenario is happening but, matching your development and production environments should elimate these problems in future.

---

**Homestead** [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead)

The Homestead vagrant box provided by the Laravel team is a solid choice and well documented. It is an Ubuntu 18.04 / 20.04 machine and can be configured with many add-ons. You can easily configure which version of PHP any given project is using with a single line in the `Homestead.yaml` file.

**Docker** [Docs](https://www.docker.com/get-started)

Docker is a little more advanced but very flexible in how it can be configured. It's container design allows you to isolate the dependencies of one project from the next.

---

These aren't that difficult to setup (easily done within a day or two) and allow you to replicate your production environments almost perfectly.

It will help massively in those "but it works on my machine" moments!